# *ngFor - two different arrays for single row on table

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, angular

I need to populate table with two different arrays "A" and "B" into a same row.

```
let A = ["a","b","c","d"]
let B = ["success","success","success","success"];
```

HTML

```
<tbody>
  <ng-container *ngFor="let alphabet of A; let i = index">
  <tr *ngFor="let status of B; let i = index">
  <td >{{ alphabet }}</td>
  <td >{{ status }}</td>
  </tr>
  </ng-container>
</tbody>
```

But here with this i get repeated set of rows

Expected:

```
a    success
b    success
c    success
d    success
```

Comment: Not found any issue with your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the the data of the second array by its index:

```
<tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let alphabet of A; let i = index">
  <td >{{ alphabet }}</td>
  <td >{{ B[i] }}</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```